# pytransform PytransformError

Tags: python

i have issue with the pytransform when i was make it as exe file
first i make the command `PYARMOR obfuscate file.py`
the output file work 100%
but when i convert the file to exe by the command

```
pyinstaller --onefile file.py
```

the file.exe show this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wineaccess_main.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "pytransform\__init__.py", line 341, in pyarmor_runtime
  File "pytransform\__init__.py", line 336, in pyarmor_init
  File "pytransform\__init__.py", line 301, in _load_library
pytransform.PytransformError: Could not find "C:\Users\Allah\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI79242\pytransform\platforms\windows\x86\_pytransform.dll"
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as you, but have found a working solution.You can convert to exe using pyarmor directly, with the following code.

```
pyarmor pack -e " --onefile" foo.py
```

Answer (score 0):

you should include lib pytransform in your command
in my case obfuscate using pyarmor and pkg using pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console \
--add-data "API;API/"\
--add-data "pytransform/_pytransform.dll;." \
--add-data "pytransform;pytransform/" \
--hidden-import "schedule"  \
--hidden-import "flask" \
--hidden-import "pytransform" \
"main.py"
```